# Twilio CLient JS Token does not allow outgoing calls

Tags: javascript, salesforce, twilio, apex, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio Client SDK and Salesforce to make calls from the browser, it is giving me strange behavior, sometime it successfully making a connection and able to make a call and sometime it is giving me error that Toke does not allow outgoing calls. Here is the dbug:

```
 VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Setting up VSP
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 WSTransport.open() called...
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Attempting to connect...
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Closing and cleaning up WebSocket...
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 No WebSocket to clean up.
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Device callback handlers (connect, error, offline, 
incoming, cancel, ready, disconnect)         have been deprecated and will 
be removed in the next breaking release. Instead, the EventEmitter         
interface can be used to set event listeners. Example: device.on('incoming', handler)
Log.log @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
Log.warn @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
Device._addHandler @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
Device.incoming @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
(anonymous) @ TwilioClick2Dial?ph=923334178796&time=1:41
TwilioClick2Dial?ph=923334178796&time=1:61 before!!!
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 WebSocket opened successfully.
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 [PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have- 
 local-offer"
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Received HANGUP from gateway
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Received an error from the gateway: {code: 31002, 
 connection: Connection, message: "Token does not allow outgoing calls."}
Log.log @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
Log.error @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
Connection._this._onHangup @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
emitOne @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
emit @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
PStream._handleTransportMessage @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
emitOne @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
emit @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
WSTransport._this._onSocketMessage @ VM3217 twilio.min.js:55
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Uncaught error event suppressed.
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 Disconnecting...
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is 
"closed"
VM3217 twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a token that doesn't have the "allow outgoing connections" capability token.

For using twilio client you need a token, which is created from your account SID, your auth token and a list of capabilities that you want to allow the token user to use.

For example to generate a token with outgoing calls capability, it would be something like this:

```
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'secret'
application_sid = 'AP123123'

capability = ClientCapabilityToken(account_sid, auth_token)
capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid)
print(capability.to_jwt())
```

You can refer to the [following doc page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/capability-tokens) to see how to create tokens with different capabilities.